# Knockout not detecting change

Tags: knockout.js

I have a page with a knockout.js model.  I am 'serializing' the data to a textbox in JSON format by binding a computed property of the serialized object.

**Selection of the parts that work:**

**View Model**

```
function CourseParticipant(name, facility) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.facility = ko.observable(facility);
}

function CourseParticipantViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.participants = ko.observableArray();
    self.participants.push(new CourseParticipant("Greg", "init"));

    self.addParticipant = function(participant) {
        self.participants.push(new CourseParticipant("", ""));
    }

    self.removeParticipant = function(participant) {
        self.participants.remove(participant);
    }

    self.serializedValue = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.toJSON(self.participants(), null, null);
    }, self);
}

ko.applyBindings(new CourseParticipantViewModel());


$("#btn").click(function(){
    $(".fac").val('val');
})
```

**HTML**

```
<table class='pc-tbl'>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: participants">

  <tr><td colspan='100%'>
      <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeParticipant">x</a></td></tr>
  <tr>
       <th>Name:</th>
       <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Facility:</th>
    <td><input data-bind="value: facility" class='fac' /></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br />
<textarea data-bind="value: serializedValue()" style='width:300px; height:100px;'></textarea>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: addParticipant">Add Participant</a>

<input type=button id='btn' value='test'  />
```

The part I am having trouble with is getting Knockout to detect the change when form is edited via JavaScript. A sample of the issue can be found here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/oglester/tQzu2/

The issue is that when you click the test button and it updates the form, the model is not updated. How do I force the form to notify the View Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because changing input value via `val()` method does not fire `change` event. Try to trigger `change` event manually after changing input value

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $(".fac").val('val');
    $(".fac").trigger('change');
})
```

But this may not work if binding trigger set to other value than 'change'.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zSmSY/

Answer (score 3):

Do it the other way around: http://jsfiddle.net/tQzu2/1/

Knockout updates the UI based on its model, i.e. you're binding the elements to the model and not vice versa.

Comment: I thought of that, but in actual code I was passing off the textbox as a reference to function like `$('.fac').click(function(){func(this);})`.  But a good answer nonetheless.